# as.POSIXct turns a tibble of times into a bunch of numbers

Tags: r, datetime

I have a tibble `my_column` with a column of strings like this:

```
'1/25/2018 0:00:00'
'11/14/2019 14:25:00'
'4/7/2019 9:31:53'
```

When I run

```
lapply(my_column, as.POSIXct, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I get back a bunch of large numbers, not datetimes like I want it. What is causing this undesired behavior, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce, I get dates. Tested with `my_column <- c('1/25/2018 0:00:00','11/14/2019 14:25:00','4/7/2019 9:31:53')` But no need for `lapply` here anyway. `as.POSIXct(my_column, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` should work fine. It's vectorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `lapply()`, because `asPOSIXct()` is a vectorized function, as many of the R's functions. When you use `lapply()`, the outputs are stored inside a list and you'll have problems to assign it as a table column.

If you want to return a vector, so you can assign it to your table column, you can do:

```
df$my_column = as.POSIXct(df$my_column, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Or you can use **lubridate** library, which is slightly more efficient. Like this:

```
library(lubridate)
df$my_column <- parse_date_time(df$my_column, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Here is the output:

```
[1] "2018-01-25 00:00:00 -02" "2019-11-14 14:25:00 -03" "2019-04-07 09:31:53 -03"
```

Note the difference between the output as a vector (using vectorized function) and the output when using `lapply()`, as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2018-01-25 -02"

[[2]]
[1] "2019-11-14 14:25:00 -03"

[[3]]
[1] "2019-04-07 09:31:53 -03"
```